# How to convert ImageView image to byte code by using Base64 encode?

Tags: android, image, imageview, encode

I am working with an image. In my application I have displayed an image from drawable and set that drawable image to ImageView. When I click on a button I would like to encode the ImageView image to byte code by using Base64.

I have implemented code as follows:

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.person);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Get((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)) image Base64.encode() here");
    }
});
```

How can I get the encoded imageView1 image to byte code?

Can anybody please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("byte array:"+image);

    String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
    System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
```

Now set that string to your Textview as

```
    tv.setText(img_str);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to always compress the image while encoding to Base64? Is it possible to directly convert an image/imagefile into Base64 encoded String without compressing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code,

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.person)
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bMap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
//bMap is the bitmap object
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public String encode(Bitmap icon) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        String test = Base64.encodeBytes(data);
        return test;
    }`
```

Comment: how can i get the imageView1 in Bitmap?

Comment: Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.person);